# How to differentiate profiles?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two types of user: `client`, `manager`. are stored in separated tables.

Each of then have unique nickname.

So, I need to open profile by `nickname`.

For Client is:

```
$client = Client::where("nickname", $nickname)
```

For Manager is:

```
$manager = Manager::where("nickname", $nickname)
```

So, I try to make universal function that dewtect where is client and manager and execute the appropriate query.

How can I improve this code and detect type of user only by nickename?

Comment: to me its better to use same table for both of the user type. just add a column to determine if that user is a manager or client. when you check a user, determine his role depends on his corresponding role column value

Comment: I'm with @reza, unless the models differ in such a way that you need to split it.

Comment: saw the two solutions bellow I still think its better in that particular use case just use 2 lines check if client if not check if manager if not return 404; will be a lot more simpler and better readability to understand what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one model for this, I guess it would be best way to handle clients and managers.

If for some reason you want to use two models, you can create method and put it in `Client` model since most of queries will be for clients:

```
public function getClientOrManagerByNickname($nickname) {
    $client = $this->where('nickname', $nickname)->first();

    return is_null($client) ? (new Manager)->where('nickname', $nickname)->first() : $client;
}
```

This code will create one query if client is found and will return this client. Or it will create two queires and will return manager. If there is no client and manager with this nickname, it will return `null`.

Comment: I would suggest creating a helper function maybe, or at least something completly detached from a model. I think that having a Model function being able to return a different model could lead to big confusion situations. 

Anyhow I think that the code is the way to go though, clean and simple ;)

Comment: Can you share sample?

Comment: @UmbertP why do you want to detach it from the model if it's 100% data related functionality? There is no perfect solution here (well, perfect solution would be keeping all data in one model). You can create repository, but I wouldn't do it for just a simple task.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I would do it cause to me it would create confusion to use:
`$client = Client::getByNickname();` to then realise that the $client is actually a Manager, instead of that I would probably complicate it a bit more for the sake of not having a Model returning another Model. I would probably do a previous step something along `$modelname = getModelName()` to return the Model type and then `$values=$modelName::where(1);`

Comment: You can call it `getClientOrManagerByNickname()`

Comment: Still my problem would be having in inside the "wrong" model. But that's only my opinion ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I said I would suggest something a bit more complex but that to me would be less prone to make mistakes because of a confusion on the Model returned.

I would suggest something along this:

`$modelname = getModelName(); $values = $modelName::where(1);`

Where the function `getModelName()` would just return the ModelName. 
I'm aware that this implies going through the DB another time and it increases the cost of the operation but I would rather loss a bit of performance and have more coherence in the code.

That's my personal opinion though.